# Can we hold atomic hydrogen for a long time?

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, molecules

If we take atomic hydrogen with similar spin together, can we hold it in balloon?  I know, that the atom is hydrogen is reactive. But when all atoms will have similar spin, reactions between them will not appear from Pauli exclusion principle? Can we use it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Normal hydrogen gas is diatomic. Monatomic hydrogen is very reactive.

Comment: "is it possible to buy a long piece of string?" ─ yes, or no, depending on what you mean by "long", and what you're willing to accept as "string". What do you mean by "for a long time"? what do you want to do with that hydrogen, and what type of conditions are you envisioning?

Comment: If it's a big enough balloon (i.e. on the scale of lightyears), and the hydrogen atoms inside are far enough apart to basically never react (i.e. a few atoms per cc), then sure, this is how you get 21cm lines in radio astronomy - from giant clouds of very, very diffuse atomic hydrogen. That said, such a structure is pretty far from what you'd normally think of as a "balloon".

Comment: To hold atomic hydrogen is possible with high temperatures only. - To hold the spins all in the same direction, you need an external magnetic field. If you consider the atoms spin to be the summarized magnetic dipoles of the involved subatomic particles, only an external field prevents the atoms from a random distribution in 3D. BTW, Paulis principle is formulated for inner atomic and molecule interactions. In a bulk of atoms the the spin distribution is randomly orientated because of the thermic motion. Ultracold matter could form Bose-Einstein-Condensates with self-aligned magnetic dipoles.